# Script redirect by referrer url

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, href, document.write

Is it possible to write redirect script by using referrer url and get div element? Something like below:

Referrer is - sitename.com/example/#bang1#bang2#bang3

Redirect site - a href="http://anothersite.com/"id="redirectthis">Redirect this

Tried -

```
<script>
var separator1 = (document.referrer.indexOf('[tag]') !== 1)
var separator2 = (document.referrer.indexOf('[tag]') !== 2)
var separator3 = (document.referrer.indexOf('[tag]') !== 3)
var relocate = document.write(document.getElementById("redirectthis") + separator1 + separator3 + separator2);
window.location = relocate
</script>
```

Result wanted - This would lead a redirect to http://anothersite.com/bang1/bang3/bang2

Comment: *document.getElementById("redirectthis")* this part result to a string like '[object]' so no , in this way you can not.

Comment: also read this. cause document.write does not any value, it's a void. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp